# SearchIndexClient.GetIndexesAsync(CancellationToken) - Token Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, azure, azure-sdk-.net

I am trying to replace Azure.Search  to Azure.Search.Document.

Here i am finding a issue in the GetIndexesAsync Method , where this method requires a cancellation token.

I just want how this need to be implemented so that we can get that token and proceed further.

Please help.

I tried implementing the Cancellation token but it didn't work for me .
need  help to understand its exact way to implement.

Comment: You use a [`CancellationTokenSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource?view=net-8.0) to create a token via its `Token` property. Did you do that?

Comment: @user23230133 Can you share the code you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

*I tried a sample C# console code with Azure.Search.Documents package to retrieve Azure Search Indexes using a cancellation token.*

**Code :**

```cs
using Azure;
using Azure.Search.Documents;
using Azure.Search.Documents.Indexes;
using Azure.Search.Documents.Indexes.Models;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        string searchServiceEndpoint = "<SearchService_Endpoint>";
        string adminApiKey = "<API_admin_key>";

        Uri serviceEndpoint = new Uri(searchServiceEndpoint);
        AzureKeyCredential credential = new AzureKeyCredential(adminApiKey);
        SearchIndexClient indexClient = new SearchIndexClient(serviceEndpoint, credential);

        using (CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource())
        {
            try
            {
                cts.CancelAfter(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

                await GetIndexesAsync(indexClient, cts.Token);
            }
            catch (TaskCanceledException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Operation was canceled.");
            }
            catch (RequestFailedException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error getting indexes: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }

    static async Task GetIndexesAsync(SearchIndexClient indexClient, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        await foreach (Page<SearchIndex> page in indexClient.GetIndexesAsync(cancellationToken: cancellationToken).AsPages())
        {
            foreach (SearchIndex result in page.Values)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Index Name: {result.Name}");
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Indexes retrieved successfully!");
    }
}
```

**Output :**

The code ran successfully and retrieved the index as below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The cancellation token parameter of [GetIndexesAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.search.documents.indexes.searchindexclient.getindexesasync?view=azure-dotnet) is optional and does not need to be passed if you do not wish to cancel the operation.

It can be called simply as:

```cs
client.GetIndexesAsync();
```

In the real world, you'd use it similar to:

```cs
await foreach (var result in client.GetIndexesAsync())
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Index Name: {result.Name}");
}
```